# How should i solve my method access security in c#?

Tags: c#, security, methods

I am working on Point-of-Sale project which is given to our company by a special bank.Bank has provided a DLL which interacts with POS via USB port.I have added that DLL which is written in .NET C# language, So no interoperability problems exists.There is a method inside DLL which is called `DebitAndShareTheAmount`.This method has two main parameter `P1,P2`.

`P1` is the Amount in plaintext and the `P2` is the amount which should be subtracted from `P1` again in plaintext.So if i call `DebitAndShare(1000,10);` //it will actually at bank credit my account with 1000-10=990$ and the shop using my app 10$.

The problem is that anybody with some basic knowledge of C# programming and access to that SHOP's computer can install Visual Studio and use that DLL and call the DebitAndShare method and you know the rest.Actually our app is going to act as service provider and available in special shops around the country , the owners of the shop will be paid by giving service available in our app to customers and take their amount(10$).I am going to have a meeting with POS developers about the security issue i just mentioned.

I have gone through the MCTS book and in security section of book, I find out that if the bank DLL uses `PublisherIdentityPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, CertFile=@"SomeCert.cer")` attribute before DebitAndShare method and mark this method as Protected then we can have one level of security, is that right? what are your suggestions.I also think if bank can give us the encryption algorithm approach , then it will also suffice.

Comment: If someone has unfettered physical access to your machine, the game is already lost. Focus on preventing that.

Comment: Why tamper with the DLL when I can just attach the POS directly to my laptop via USB and do all sorts of stuff with it?

Comment: you both are right.What is solution?

Comment: Does not the bank check for some credentials or validate from where the request is coming? Like you send some token encrypted using key issued by bank or you.. just a thought.

Comment: code access security won't help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is stop your app from being cracked, this is similar to a [licensing issue i faced previously](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117664/licensing-for-a-web-based-desktop-application), i haven't got any great solutions from the community, but only some  good suggestions, the point here is no matter how hard you try, as long as you are executing the code on a machine your user has access to, it is always susceptible, leave alone code obfuscation, even encryption can't protect your app some times from a determined cracker with enough skill, and judging by the profitability of messing with your application, there will be many determined one(the only thing is they need to know that it can be done, and they will find some one with the skill).

I might sound like a pessimist here, but that is the hard truth.

**The best approach according to me would be to move the parts of the code that are more likely to be cracked to a central server, and expose those methods as web-services calls**. I know even this is not completely secure, remember the **[recent Apple app store hack](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13579_3-57471929-37/new-ios-hack-yields-in-app-freebies/)**. Make sure you have followed all the best practices and hope, you will find a crack in your system before anybody else does

Comment: I would also go this route. Put your weakly-secured components behind a service so you can add as many additional layers of security as is necessary to compensate. You could then require things such as usernames, passwords, FOBs, etc. to authenticate the transaction, have the service challenge with additional forms of authentication, and only once you're certain it's from an authorized user, allow the DLL to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, you are going to have a serious problem securing this. However, a few approaches come to mind that would at least help.

1. Walk the stack. In your callsite, look at the current stack, and walk back up. If you see anything that isn't what you expect, then fail. This isn't foolproof, but it will stop people who aren't skilled and/or can see your source code.
2. Use a SecureString and an outside secret. This requires that you have some means of getting a secure value from somewhere. Once you have that, you can encrypt/sign data to ensure that it isn't been tampered with (via certs or some other mechanism). A debugger (a la WinDBG) will still be able to break it, but less easily.
3. Rebuild your code in C++. Machine code is harder to find, but this still won't stop someone who knows windows internals.

Instead of trying to empty the ocean by securing your app, you can take a number of measures, and then do what the banks do. Look for patterns that don't make sense. If a particular POS usually generates values on the order of 100, when you see a large or small order, flag it for review. A sudden increase in transactions? Same thing.

Aside from technical solutions, your best bet (IMHO) is to make sure that the shops are partially on the hook for fraud. Money on the line causes people to be a bit more careful as to who has access to the computer.

Erick

Comment: This wouldn't actually do much to secure anything. Somewhere the state that matters (account balances) is saved, and that's where it needs to be secured. In my view, chances are the OP has misunderstood something about how this works in production - or else, he needs to explain to the customer why their solution is not secure. Pretending that a call stack can protect the DB or whatever it is they use will only make matters worse, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You could have it so that the function accepts something like your pin so that the function calls the bank database to check your pin is correct. That way at least if someone gets access, they'll have to disable the pin argument first.

You could also follow the Gabe approach and have the system map the account to a device and make it so the function can only be accessed from a registered device. Also, perhaps making it so the source code isn't stored on a bank computer, but on a storage device in a bank vault/safety deposit box. Then the person actually has to rob the bank to get at it. As a double measure, encrypt/set a password to the device so only the decryption algorithm (on the bank's system, which the robbers are unlikely to go back for) or the known password can extract the source code.

If that doesn't work, I have no more sensible ideas (unless keeping the source in the recycle bin or locking the source in a nuclear bunker counts as sensible).

Answer (score -2):

We should be using delayed signing. Bank's authorized person deploys the rightly signed dll in the device.  Bank signs it with their private key.

All calls through this will be authentic and all others are hacking requests.

Comment: How would that help? Code signing isn't useful at all in the OP's situation.